# IR Obstacle Sensor and Comparator circuit

Tags: arduino

I need to measure the rpm of my BLDC motor. The sensor I'm using if the IR obstacle sensor. However, the reading of the rpm is not defined and kept on changing even though the speed of the motor is constant. My supervisor said that I should use a comparator to eliminate any noise that causes the undefined rpm reading. I'm in a tight spot right now, I have difficulty trying to understand the use of comparator and how it can be used to obtain a good steady rpm measurement. Can anyone explain it to me and show me the circuit for comparator?

Comment: This is a programming site. Hardware questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, IR obstacle sensor has onboard comparators. But if you want to make comparator yourself use [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-IR-Sensor-using-Op-amp-and-Arduino/) method.

Comment: So just to be sure... this is the IR sensor I'm using, here is the link http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-609348425-modulo-detector-sensor-obstaculos-infrarrojo-arduino-nubbeo-_JM... this sensor already has an onboard comparator?? This is because, my supervisor kept telling me to use a comparator circuit when using IR obstacle sensor so that i can get a steady reading of rpm.

Comment: The sensor you said already have a comparator onboard. Its referance voltage can be changed by the knob. Now the main thing is making a code which is stable and have low complexity. I will recommend this method http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Motor-Speed-Tester-Tachometer/